# Underscore.js - array to object with same key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I need to convert this:

```
"colors":["pink", "Blue"]
```

or simply this

```
["pink", "Blue"]
```

into this

```
[{ colors: "pink" }, { colors: "blue" }]
```

in order to be able to use it in AngularJS. Is there any way to do it using underscore.js? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The use of underscore.js is mandatory?

Comment: No, I have been trying to do it with underscore.js as I am new in Javascript, but I guess with simple Javascript is OK :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Underscore provides the `_.map()` method, which will allow you to accomplish what you're looking for.

```
var arr = ['pink','blue'];
var hash = _.map(arr, function(color){ return {colors: color};});
```

However, undercore's map method is simply a thin wrapper around the native `Array#map` method in javascript, which can be used as follows:

```
var arr = ['pink', 'blue'];
var hash = arr.map(function(color){ return {colors: color}; });
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
var newArray = new Array();
colors.forEach(function(item) {
    newArray.push({colors: item});
});
```

Comment: You're not strictly wrong, but it is idiomatic to use `map()` in this case

Comment: I've marked the other one as correct, but many thanks for the help!

Comment: @RickyTomatoes it's been a long day, I've corrected the code :)

Comment: @Matt although it looks syntactically nicer with map, it is actually equal, if not a little bit faster, in the performance. And the fastest would probably be with a "normal" for loop

Comment: @FranePoljak Removing my earlier comment in acknowledgement of the correction. I ran a quick perf test on these cases, forEach came out on top, followed by using a for loop, with map bringing up the rear. The difference, however, wouldn't be noticeable except in extremely demanding performance situations

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you have an object like this:

```
var obj = {
   key1: ['val1_1', 'val1_2'],
   key2: ['val2_1', 'val2_2']
}
```

and you want to get something like this:

```
var arr = [{key1: 'val1_1'}, {key1: 'val1_2'}, {key2: 'val2_1'}, {key2: 'val2_2'}]
```

out of it.

```
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
    return obj[key].map(function(item){
        var result = {};
        result[key] = item;
        return result;
    })
}).reduce(function(prevArray, newArray){
   return prevArray.concat(newArray);
}, []);
```

Or if you want the result to be like:

```
var arr = [[{key1: 'val1_1'}, {key1: 'val1_2'}], [{key2: 'val2_1'}, {key2: 'val2_2'}]]
```

just remove the last part (`.reduce(...)`) which concatenates all arrays.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is a more general case!